# Powershell issues with output

Tags: powershell, scripting, command-line-interface

issues with my output, this is my current script:

```
param ([string]$myhost = ‘localhost’)
Clear-Host
Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=True -ComputerName $myhost |  
  select-object -Property IPAddress, Mac, Description
 "{0,-10}{1,30}{2,60}" -f $_.mac, $_.ipaddress,  $_.description
```

looking on how to have my output resemble this:

```
enum-nic localhost
74:86:7A:6F:4A:CD   198.108.110.80   fe80::7dd5:140c:90d3:9be2   Broadcom
NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
```

this is my current output:

```
IPAddress                                  Mac Description                      
---------                                  --- -----------                      
{192.168.87.34, fe80::10c3:482e:799e:85bb}     Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter
```

Please and thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are wanting to control the PowerShell output as a text stream. That is not how PowerShell naturally works. There would need to be explicit text formatting to control the output.

PowerShell's nature is to output objects. Does this get you what you want?

```
C:>Get-Content .\enum-nic.ps1
param ([string]$myhost = 'localhost')
Clear-Host
Get-WmiObject -class win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=True -ComputerName $myhost |
    Select-Object -Property IPAddress, MacAddress, Description |
    ForEach-Object { "{0,-18}{1,16}{2,30}   {3}" -f $_.MacAddress, $_.IPAddress[0],  $_.IPAddress[1], $_.Description }
```

Output from a sample run.

```
0A:00:27:00:00:09     192.168.56.1     fe80::79aa:55e9:56de:bb9b   VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
FC:AA:14:0D:7C:86     192.168.0.62     fe80::5199:d760:a95d:bda4   Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
00:15:5D:16:E9:68     172.28.144.1     fe80::cc8f:e85d:ec8f:42e2   Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
76:15:76:DB:53:BC   172.25.156.225     fe80::6190:503c:ed81:123f   Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
```

Comment: Worked perfectly